# Create and iterate through three dimensional JSON object

Tags: arrays, json

I've looked at quite some topics about the matter on this site, but i can't seem to find a understandable solution for my approach.

I have a situation where i want to fill three select boxes with options from a multidimensional (JSON ?) array with a relation like this:

```
Country > Region > City
```

Every country has multiple regions and each region has multiple cities

I thought of something like this

```
var destination = {
    'country' : 'Germany',
    'area' : [{
        'Beieren' : [{
            'city' : [{
                '0' : 'Mitwitz'
            }],
        }],
        'Beieren Beierse Woud' : [{
            'city' : [{
                '0' : 'St. Englmar', 
                '1' : 'Waldmünchen', 
                '2' : 'Arrach'
            }],
        }],
    }],
};
```

But apparently that isn't the way to go since `destination.country` gives me the last occurrence of country (Germany in this case) but then i get stuck.

I probably took a wrong turn somewhere in the making of the data array, but i don't know how to het back on track.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

With some help i got it working like so:

```
var destination = [
    {
        'country': 'Germany',
        'area': [
            {
                'name': 'Beieren',
                'cities': [
                    'Mitwitz'
                ],
            }, 
            {
                'name': 'Beieren Beierse Woud',
                'cities': [
                    'St. Englmar', 
                    'Waldmünchen', 
                    'Arrach'
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
];

console.log(destination[0].area[1].cities[1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var destination = [
    {
        'country': 'Germany',
        'area': [
            {
                'name': 'Beieren',
                'cities': [
                    'Mitwitz'
                ],
            }, 
            {
                'name': 'Beieren Beierse Woud',
                'cities': [
                    'St. Englmar', 
                    'Waldmünchen', 
                    'Arrach'
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
];

console.log(destination[0].area[1].cities[1]);
```